# Filter documents to be seen by a certain Role in OrionJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, roles

If `myRole.helper('collections.myCollection.indexFilter', {});` allows all documents to be seen, how do I limit it to only documents created by the user? I'm following [OrionJS documentation](http://docs.orionjs.org/v1.7/roles) where there's an example:

```
/**
 * Set the index filter.
 * This part is very important and sometimes is forgotten.
 * Here you must specify which documents the role will be able to see in the index route
 */
myRole.helper('collections.myCollection.indexFilter', {}); // Allows the role to se all documents
```

This example shows all documents to `myRole` but I want to limit it to only documents created by them. I tried `myRole.helper('collections.myCollection.indexFilter', { createdBy: this.userId });` but that didn't show any documents. I have indeed created some documents with a user belong to `myRole` (and the `createdBy` key does exist), which I do see when the filter is off, so what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - the filter needs to be a function:

```
myRole.helper('collections.myCollection.indexFilter', function() {
  return {
    createdBy: this.userId
  }
});
```